# Copying and pasting from one data frame to another data frame in R

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames. the first data frame has NA on it. I want to use another data frame to replace those `NA` in the first data frame. the first data frame has 30 unique id while the 2nd data frame only has 8 unique id. I want to copy the weight data on the 2nd data frame on to the first data frame that matches the id regardless of the date on all id present on df2. Please help. I'm really stuck at this part. I'm still beginner

```
df1
id            date      calories    weight
1503960366 2016-04-12     1985        NA
1503960366 2016-04-13     1797        NA
1503960366 2016-04-14     1776        NA
1503960366 2016-04-15     1745        NA
1503960366 2016-04-16     1863        NA
1503960366 2016-04-17     1728        NA
1503960366 2016-04-18     1921        NA
1503960366 2016-04-19     2035        NA
1503960366 2016-04-20     1786        NA
1503960366 2016-04-21     1775        NA
1503960366 2016-04-22     1827        NA
```

and so on

```
df2
id            date      calories    weight
1503960366 2016-05-02     2004      52.6
1503960366 2016-05-03     1990      52.6
1927972279 2016-04-13     2151     133.5
2873212765 2016-04-21     1970      56.7
```

and so on

Here are the codes that I tried.

```r
df3 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(weight = ifelse(id == df2$id,
                            df2$weight, weight))

df3 <- df1 %>%
  select(.)
  mutate(
    weight = ifelse(
      id == df2$id ,
      paste(df2$weight_kg), NA_character_) )
```

What I want to happen is like this

```
id            date      calories    weight
1503960366 2016-04-12     1985        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-13     1797        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-14     1776        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-15     1745        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-16     1863        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-17     1728        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-18     1921        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-19     2035        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-20     1786        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-21     1775        52.6
1503960366 2016-04-22     1827        52.6
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for the merge function. It searches for the ID in df2 and will replace the NAs in df1 with the weight.

here is a reproducable example

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("1503960366", "1503960366"),
                  date = c("2016-04-12", "2016-04-12"),
                  calories = c(1985, 2012),
                  weight = NA)

df2 <- data.frame(id = c("1503960366"),
                  date = c("2016-04-12"),
                  calories = c(1985),
                  weight = 52.6)
```

then i merge the two dataframes:

```
merged_df <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

merged_df

```
          id       date calories.x weight.x calories.y weight.y
1 1503960366 2016-04-12       1985       NA       1985     52.6
2 1503960366 2016-04-12       2012       NA       1985     52.6
```

finally. we can get rid of the columns we dont want.

```
df <- subset(merged_df, select = c(-3, -4))
names(df) <- c("id", "date", "calories", "weight")
df
          id       date colories weight
1 1503960366 2016-04-12     1985   52.6
2 1503960366 2016-04-12     1985   52.6
```

Another possibility would be to use the coalesce function:
library(dplyr)

```
merged_df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("id", "date")) %>%
  mutate(weight = coalesce(weight.x, weight.y)) %>%
  select(id, date, calories = calories.x, weight)

print(merged_df)
          id       date calories weight
1 1503960366 2016-04-12     1985   52.6
2 1503960366 2016-04-12     2012   52.6
```

This code performs a left join to merge the dataframes df1 and df2 based on the columns "id" and "date". The coalesce() function is then used to replace the NAs in the "weight" column.